# LLVM: bitcode with llvm-gcc (mingw) for windows

Tags: mingw, llvm, llvm-gcc

i'm currently building a small JIT compiler.
For the language I need a runtime library for some special math functions.
I think the best would be to compile the lib to bitcode and link it. 
The compiler should be integrated in a product and as of this, it must work under windows (VC10, 64bit).

So is it possible to build the math lib with the mingw llvm-gcc build an link it later with the JITed Code?
Or are there any problems regarding the portability of the bitcode build with llvm-gcc under mingw?
If there are problems, what solution would you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Bitcode is in a portable format (at least given the same architecture); there is no difference between bitcode generated in Windows and bitcode generated in, for example, Linux or Cygwin.

Comment: Are you sure?
I read in the FAQ that bitcode is not platform-independent.

Comment: They mean that you cannot use bitcode from ARM on your X86 system, or from X86/64 on X86/32 (differently sized longs/ints, other calling conventions, different struct alignments etc)
Also they have a comment about include files being different. As long as you only use the win32 and math functions which exist in standard C (nothing cygwin specific), you're safe from that.